# AngularJS - dropdown menu using ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been working on a project and trying to create a dropdownmenu using AngularJs. But i can't get the employeId info on the menu to select. If more code detail is needed, i can add.

Here is the [image of dropdownmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykv3i.png)

**Delete.html**

```
     <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="drop">
            {{selectedItem}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="a in emps">
                <a ng-click="dropboxitemselected(a)">{{a.Id}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Demo.js**

```
MyApp.controller("DeleteController", function ($scope, EmpApi) {
    $scope.selectedItem = "Select Employee";
    $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = false;
    getEmployees();
    function getEmployees() {
        EmpApi.getEmployees().then(function (response) {
            $scope.emps = emps;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load emp data:' + error.message;
        })
    };
    $scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item.Id;
        $scope.name = item.Name;
        $scope.age = item.Age;
        $scope.sal = item.Salary;
        $scope.empid = item.Id;
        $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = true;
    };
    $scope.DeleteEmp = function () {
        var empToDelete = {
            'Id': $scope.empid
        };
        EmpApi.DeleteEmployee(empToDelete)
                .then(function (response) {
                    alert("user deleted");
                    $scope.name = undefined;
                    $scope.age = undefined;
                    $scope.sal = undefined;
                    $scope.empid = undefined;
                    $scope.selectedItem = "Select Employee";
                    $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = false;
                    getEmployees();
                })
            .catch(function (response) {
                alert("error in deleting");
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the issue, but in your `getEmployees` function, you're assigning `$scope.emps = emps` but you're not passing `emps` as the parameter in your `.then` callback function. You're passing `response`.

Answer (score 0):

First error, you are invoking `getEmployees()` before it's defined. 
Add the line after the function is defined. I would recommend you to add it as a last line in the controller definition to make it more clear.

Second error is in the `EmpApi.getEmployees()` promise where you are setting `$scope.emps = emps;` where emps is not defined.
Set the  `$scope.emps = response` or `$scope.emps = response.data` depending on your implmenetation

Controller:

```
MyApp.controller("DeleteController", function ($scope, EmpApi) {
    $scope.selectedItem = "Select Employee";
    $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = false;

    function getEmployees() {
        EmpApi.getEmployees().then(function (response) {
            $scope.emps = response;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load emp data:' + error.message;
        })
    };

    $scope.dropboxitemselected = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item.Id;
        $scope.name = item.Name;
        $scope.age = item.Age;
        $scope.sal = item.Salary;
        $scope.empid = item.Id;
        $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = true;
    };
    $scope.DeleteEmp = function () {
        var empToDelete = {
            'Id': $scope.empid
        };
        EmpApi.DeleteEmployee(empToDelete)
                .then(function (response) {
                    alert("user deleted");
                    $scope.name = undefined;
                    $scope.age = undefined;
                    $scope.sal = undefined;
                    $scope.empid = undefined;
                    $scope.selectedItem = "Select Employee";
                    $scope.isDeleteItemVisible = false;
                    getEmployees();
                })
            .catch(function (response) {
                alert("error in deleting");
            });

        //Init
        getEmployees();
    }
```